# Pass render function to slot in Vue3

Tags: vue.js, rendering, slot

I have a component TopBar

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { h } from 'vue';

const props = withDefaults(defineProps<{ height?: number }>(), { height: 50 });

const spacer = () => h('span', { class: 'bar__spacer' } );
</script>

<template>
  <div class="bar" :style="{ '--height': props.height }">
    <slot :spacer="spacer"></slot>
  </div>
</template>

<style scoped lang="scss">
.bar {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 0 calc(var(--height) * 1px);
  width: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 10px;
  background-color: var(--bg-top-bar);
  border-bottom: 1px solid var(--bg-separator);

  &__spacer {
    flex-grow: 1;
  }
}
</style>
```

When I'm using it, I want to add `spacer` as HTML element. So it'll look like this:

```
    <TopBar v-slot="{ spacer }">
      Some content goes here...
      <spacer/>
      Some more content there...
    </TopBar>
```

But it didn't work. The spacer tag renders as `<spacer/>`. Any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `<component :is="">` syntax, i.e.

```html
<TopBar v-slot="{ spacer }">
  <component :is="spacer"/>
</TopBar>
```

[Playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)